# Mobile app automation testing using Appium

Tags: android, selenium, android-studio, testng, appium

I am facing an error during the installation of Appium for mobile automation testing. I have installed android studio in drive G instead of C. When I start the session it shows the error below:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error:

Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Thinkcenter\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources
\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'.
Original error: Error: could not open `G:\androidsdk\platform-tools\lib\jvm.cfg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that pops into my mind is setting up your environment variables correctly (does not do that automatically when installing Android Studio), but you may first want to debug your environment through appium-doctor.

**Option 1**
Use NPM (Node.js package manager) to install *appium-doctor* globally from cmd:

```
npm install -g appium-doctor
```

run appium-doctor to check all your environment settings for Android:

```
appium-doctor --android
```

Make sure everything in the section *### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###* is green

**Option 2**
Check your environment variables

1. Add a **new path** on system level: Name = "ANDROID_HOME", value = "G:\PATH\TO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
2. Add **two new values** to the already existing variable: "*Path*" on system level (open it in the list of system variables): Add these values (1) "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools", (2) "ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools"

**Edit: Option 3**
I have seen your screenshot and I see some problems with your Desired Capabilities. Set the correct ones the following way:

1. platformName: "Android"
2. platformVersion: [API 28 = "9"]
3. deviceName: "emulator-5554"

- *now appPackage and appActivity are the important part - you have to define both full paths if you don't have an .apk file*

3. appPackage: "com.android.calculator2"
4. appActivity: "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"

*Don't know the appPackage and appActivity? use Apk Analyze (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.styk.martin.apkanalyzer&hl=nl&gl=US) to scan for .apk files and their respective appPackage and appActivity*

Comment: I have already apply both options butt not working.

Comment: @Zaman10 can you tell me the purpose of your testcase? Maybe I can dig a bit deeper for you, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the uiautomator2 server.

Comment: I want to test just UI/UX of IOS/ Android apps using Appium.

Comment: Is your appium package through npm installed globally? i.e. "npm install -g appium"

Comment: I have: Eclips editor, Android studio emulator, Appium downloaded from google and than install manually, Node js, jdk

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1jtf46k    Installed appium globally butt got the same error. https://prnt.sc/1jtfp41

Comment: I am using api 28 = 9 pie version

Comment: Not working! is you have any other solution to this problem

Comment: Please check screenshot of my Environmental variables: https://prnt.sc/1jtrqqj

Comment: Can you try and organise them like this? https://prnt.sc/1jtt97f